# Repeat string multiple times in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, static-site, templating-engine

How do you repeat string multiple times in Jekyll?

For eg: in Python, you can do `"hello" * 5` to get `'hellohellohellohellohello'`. In Jekyll is there an easier way of doing the same thing than this.

```
{% for i in (1..5) %}
  Hello
{% endfor %}
```

**Example**

Say you want to display a star rating and you are using `<i class="fa fa-star"></i>` to display each star. So to display a 5 star rating you would do.

```
{% for i in (1..5) %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
{% endfor %}
```

A single page may have many ratings displayed on it so you would be using several instances of that for loop.

Comment: No, that is the easiest way.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete use-case to help request this feature at the official repository?

Comment: @ashmaroli. Updated my question with an example use case.

Comment: I was expecting to see an example of repeated "string" but instead see a case of repeated "HTML tags" `<i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>` for which, the current `for` loop is the best. You may simply extract that to an `include` and add that snippet as a single line of code (with an additional parameter signifying an active star (e.g. rating: 3 out of 5 )).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way.

If your concern is about performance; then you don't need worry because Jekyll Liquid is precompiled into html anyway so the performance will only be affected at build time.